# Копирование кода HTML

Tags: html, css

Пробую работать с Boostrap, почему при копировании с шаблонов сайта может происходить смещение налево, а не так, как в шаблоне. Сам Boostrap я скачал и сделал импорт.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/headers.css')}}">.
```

Посмотрел видео других людей у них все хорошо.

[image: Картинка]

Comment: Простите, с воображением беда. Можете примерами дополнить ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Разная версия bootstrap. Попробуйте 4-ю версию подключить, а потом 5-ю и сравнить

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставьте более развернутые ответы. Чтобы изменить ответ нажмите [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1482097/edit).

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой и ответ )